# Enable submit button with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

First, i have a code that i need to know if the user has clicked on one submit button, then, i need one function to enable another submit button that is disabled by disabled="disabled".

Here's my noob function (Needs improves, does not work).
:

```
<script>
    function EnableSend() {
    if(document.getElementById("Submit_Facebook").click(); {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false; }
    }
 </script>
```

And now the code:

1 - Disabled Submit: (Will be enabled after user click on Submit_Facebook submit button).

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="" disabled="disabled">
```

2 - Other submit that will make the disabled submit enabled.

```
<form method="post" class="button" action="<?=$PHP_SELF;?>"">
 <input id="Submit_Facebook" name="Submit_Facebook" type="submit" value=""onclick="EnableSend()">
</form>
```

3 - Php part

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit_Facebook'])) {
echo "<script>alert('You now can proceed to step two.');</script>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript"language="javascript">window.open("#");</script>'; 
exit;
}?>
```

Well, my english is not that good, but if you guys need any detail just contact me, thanks for your attention.

Comment: what are you doing in that function looks weird

Comment: the `.click()` in javascript simulates a mouse click, not to be confused with jQuery's click method which attaches an event listener.  So wrapping it in a if won't really help you here.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades - If removes the semicolon the OP will still have a broken `if` statement.  They would have to replace ';' with ')'.

Comment: @Ballbin: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kCet/)

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="send" disabled="disabled">   
<input id="Submit_Facebook" name="Submit_Facebook" type="submit" value="" onclick="EnableSend();">

<script type="text/javascript">
function EnableSend() {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You got to remove `disabled` attribute from input.

Something like this:

```
var EnableSend = function(){
  $( "#submit" ).removeAttr('disabled');
};
```